# When will LaTeX3 be released?

Tags: latex3

I'm surprised how difficult it was to google the answer to this question, so now I'm asking in here: When is LaTeX3 likely to be released? How far is development at this moment? And what is currently being worked on?

Comment: Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/953/why-is-latex3-taking-so-long-to-come-out?

Comment: Indeed I have, but I found that it gave few concrete answers. And furthermore, it is from back in 2010. Certainly some progress has been made since then?

Comment: I believe that this sort of question is [too localized in time](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#close) and there's definitely no correct answer to it.

Comment: "When it is finished"

Comment: @Gaussler We certainly have been working hard, for example getting the `expl3` and `xparse` modules stable enough for general uptake (surprisingly tricky). However, the general picture is still one where no-one from the team is going to commit to a release schedule.