# What is strategic goal of LaTeX3 project team?

Tags: latex3

@Joseph Wright in his answer to the post [Why is LaTeX3 taking so long to come out?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/953/why-is-latex3-taking-so-long-to-come-out) wrote that strategic goal of the latex3 team is a new LaTeX kernel, which should be more flexible than that of LaTeX2e (in particular, to avoid loading of add-on packages). 3 years went away since than. What is the current vision of latex3 kernel? There are more than 4k packages on CTAN. Perhaps, not more than 5 to 10% deserve to be included into new kernel. Perhaps, most frustrating thing (at least for me) it that explicit loading of some dozens packages result in loading of order of 100 packages since the most popular packages usually request lof of subsidiary packages.

My more narrow interest is which version of cross-referencing mechanism is planned to be implemented in LaTeX3? From what I am familiar with that of `zref` seems to be more promising although user interface provided by the `zref` package seems to be overcomplicated.

Comment: I guess this could be closed as "primarily opinion-based" but in any case I think it's premature to look at top level surface syntax, the current focus is on the core programming layer different top level syntax and different cross referencing schemes will no doubt be buildable on that layer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle's comment might indicate that latex3 project is a sort of pure art, that is programming for the sake of programming also known as coding for fun. Nuclear fusion is a scientific  analog of endless and resultless development.

Comment: That would be a misreading of my comment. It is just that you should not ask people designing a new kind of brick what shape houses are going to be built.