# Difference between LaTeX, LaTeX2e, LaTeX3 ?

Tags: latex3, latex-misc

I was wondering, what is the difference between `LaTeX`, `LaTeX2e` and `LaTeX3`. Are the 2 higher versions available for use? I use LaTeX. How can I use the other 2 on Windows 7?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

LaTeX2e is the latest stable release of LaTeX. When people say LaTeX they usually mean LaTeX2e, not an earlier version.

LaTeX3 is a massive refactoring of the LaTeX2e code base, which is [currently in development](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/953/why-is-latex3-taking-so-long-to-come-out).  Some of the developers are frequent contributors here and will probably chime in. You can follow the development at [LaTeX3](https://github.com/latex3/latex3) GitHub repository.

The difference to end users between LaTeX2e and LaTeX3 will be many more functionalities included "out of the box" rather than requiring packages.

The programmer's interface to LaTeX3 for class and package writers will include lots of enhancements like built-in data structures and methods to control expansion without so many `\expandafter`s.  Some current packages use the [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) package already to implement their features.

Answer (score 27):

LaTeX2e has been the current version since 1994. Every current TeX distribution supports it. LaTeX, I guess you mean LaTeX 2.09, is outdated.

LaTeX3 is a version in development, have a look at

- [What new bits have already been implemented in LaTeX3?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397/what-new-bits-have-already-been-implemented-in-latex3-will-my-current-documents)
- [Why is LaTeX3 taking so long to come out?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/953/why-is-latex3-taking-so-long-to-come-out)

With Windows 7 you can use [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) or [TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/).

Answer (score 26):

`LaTeX` is a synonym for `LaTeX2e`, which itself is the successor of `LaTeX 2.09`.
`LaTeX3` has been in development for nearly 20 years and shall be the successor of `LaTeX2e`. The main basic packages for `LaTeX3` can be used but are still in an experimental state. I suppose that a lot of `LaTeX` (which is actually `LaTeX2e`) users will be retired if `LaTeX3` should ever be officially released ... ;-)

All `TeX` distributions support `LaTeX2e` which is, of course, not a program but a macro package. The program is `tex`, `pdftex`, `luatex`, or `xetex`. They use the macro package `latex.ltx` when called as `latex`, `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, or `xelatex`.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote that for "users will be retired" `;-)`... It's not very nice.

Comment: @Bruno: Probably true, though :-)

Comment: Can anyone say Gnu Hurd? (the OS kernel that never was... in development since 1990. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Hurd .) http://www.xkcd.com/844/ --> "You can either hang out in the Android Loop or the HURD loop."

Answer (score 3):

At this point in time the plan is to evolve LaTeX incrementally rather than trying to switch to a new code base all at once. See the talk by Frank Mittelbach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNci4lcb8Vo&feature=youtu.be

So while the goals of the LaTeX3 project are coming to fruition, there are no plans currently for changing the name from LaTeX2e to LaTeX3.