# How to automatically add text immediately after \begin{document}

Tags: environments, hooks

I attempted to redefine the `document` environment as follows, but get a complaint that:

> LaTeX Error: `\begin{MYdocument}` on input line 13 ended by `\end{document}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newtoks{\SpecialText} 
\SpecialText={Text to be printed after begin document}

\newenvironment{MYdocument}{%
  \begin{document}{}
  Note: \the\SpecialText
}{%
  \end{document}
} 

\begin{MYdocument}
 ... file contents ...
\end{MYdocument}
```

I want this to produce the following output

> Note: Text to be printed after begin document
>
> ... file contents ...

If I could do this by just slightly modifying the environment that would be preferable so that I could just use `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`.

Comment: I tried to make the title of your question clearer by adding the word "text" - is that OK?

Comment: The `latex-general` tag (and also `latex3`) is for questions about LaTeX and the LaTeX project in general. A good example is [Difference between LaTeX, LaTeX2e, LaTeX3?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13541/difference-between-latex-latex2e-latex3). Your question is about a specific task and therefore should not be tagged with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2023 the answers suggesting to use `\AtBeginDocument` might be outdated. In fact, [`clsguide.pdf`](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/clsguide.pdf) has on p. 16

> The `\AtBeginDocument` hook should not be used for code that does any typesetting since the typeset result would be unpredictable.

Simplifying, the code `\begin{document}` expands to

```
\UseHook{env/document/before}
\begingroup
\def\@currenvir{document}
\UseHook{env/document/begin}
\UseOneTimeHook{begindocument/before}%
% ... global option check, size setting, aux file, font setup
\normalsize
\everypar{}%
% ... spacefactor codes, language, metadata, page size
\UseOneTimeHook{begindocument}%   <--- \AtBeginDocument goes in here
% ... other settings
\UseOneTimeHook{begindocument/end}%
\ignorespaces
```

I've marked where the content of `\AtBeginDocument` is inserted. While font sizes have been set up and `\everypar` has been "cleared" such that it doesn't throw the `Missing \begin{document}` error, other stuff goes on and, as the official guide tells, the result might be unpredictable. (Subjunctive: clearly you *might* also get lucky.) The very last hook executed by `\begin{document}`, just before `\ignorespaces`, is `begindocument/end` (see also [`lthooks-doc.pdf`](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf), p.25). Material to be typeset should thus come into this hook:

```
\documentclass{article}
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{Hello world!\par}
\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a format later than `2020-10-01`, `etoolbox`'s own `\AfterEndPreamble` is simply mapped into `\AddToHook{begindocument/end}`. With older formats it can still be used safely, because the used hook is added at the very end of `\document` by something like this:

```
\edef\document{\unexpanded\expandafter{\document Hello world!\par}}
```

Doing this yourself is clearly evil. Fluffy little bunnies will die horribly any time you do so, unless you are a dark TeX wizard/witch who really knows what he/she is doing.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that and including that info here. So, does that comment also apply to `\AfterEndPreamble` or that still ok to use.

Comment: @PeterGrill Good point, I've edited. With a modern format they're the same.

Comment: Interesting: The syntax `>!` for "spoilers" works in the preview but non in the main page. Does someone know why?

Comment: Thanks for figuring out that `\AfterEndPreamble` is still safe. I suspect the `>!` doesn't work in TeX.SE as that feature is not really used here so was only enabeled in the sites that wanted/needed it. I suspect that it works in Preview by accident. But, probably a good question to ask on Meta.

Comment: @PeterGrill To be precise: `\AfterEndPreamble` works also with older formats, just in a slightly different way. I've rephrased a bit to make this clear.

Answer (score 60):

You can use the `\AtBeginDocument` command before the `\begin{document}` line to queue up code (even multiple pieces of code) so that it it executed when that line is hit.  [Here's a reference](http://tex.loria.fr/general/new/clsguide.html#Sec%3adelays).

Comment: Thank You. That is a MUCH better solution that what I was attempting...

Comment: Note that the reference given is not up to date, see [this version](http://latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf#10). An update of december 1996 states that no typesetting can (should) be done with `\AtBeginDocument`. Check out [this](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/hyperref-and-atbegindocument/1913173) for more information on why you should not do this.

Comment: @TonioElGringo: Just saw this now. The first link you provided no longer works.  The problem file provided at the second link seems to compile fine by adding `\usepackage{tikz}`, so not sure if that is a reason to _not_ use `\AtBeginDocument{}`.  No idea why it needs `tikz`, but if someone posts that question on this site, people will explain or fix the package if it is a bug.

Answer (score 45):

As already stated by Aaron, `\AtBeginDocument{<code>}` can be used to place code "at the begin of the document". This hook is executed after the old `.aux` is read in and the new one is opened, but before the preamble is officially closed.
Therefore the code can still load packages *and* add already type-settable material which writes into the `.aux` file, like sectioning commands. So it is actually executed with one foot in the preamble and the other one in the document body.

The `etoolbox` package provides `\AfterEndPreamble{<code>}` (and other useful hooks) which is executed after the preamble is closed, so e.g. all preamble-only macros are disabled etc. Actually it is executed at the very end of `\begin{document}`, only followed by an `\ignorespaces`. I personally would prefer `\AfterEndPreamble` to `\AtBeginDocument` (already heavily used by packages) to add code at the very beginning of the document body.