# Define a command so that it is only active within the document environment

Tags: macros, environments, package-writing

I would like to configure a custom command so that it only affects the `document` environment. Because the command changes a number of catcodes, it has to be included after the `begin{document}` tag in order to work properly. However, I would prefer to set it up so that I can include it in its own `.sty` file. Is there some way to define a command so that it is only active within the `document` environment?

---

The type of code that I am trying to use is similar to the following:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
    \catcode`\_=13  \def_#1_{\emph{#1}}
}
```

When I typeset the document with the `\AtBeginDocument` command, the console stops at the `\begin{document}` line and notes the following:

```
Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
    \inaccessible
```

If I include the code (without the `\AtBeginDocument{}` rule) after the `\begin{document}` command, however, the document will process correctly.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\AtBeginDocument` to execute code at the start of the `\document` environment.  If you attempt to use `\SomeNewCommand` before `\begin{document}` you get an error.

### References:

- My second question on this site [How to automatically add text immediately after \begin{document}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14135/how-to-automatically-add-text-immediately-after-begindocument) has some explanation.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \newcommand*{\SomeNewCommand}{The command SomeNewCommand is now defined.}%
}

%\SomeNewCommand% Undefined

\begin{document}
    \SomeNewCommand
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The code you propose

```
\AtBeginDocument{
    \catcode`\_=13  \def_#1_{\emph{#1}}
}
```

can't work, because the `_` is read as an argument to `\AtBeginDocument` and so its category code is frozen.

You can do it in an indirect way:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~#1~}{\emph{#1}}%
  \catcode`_=\active
}
```

This works because `~` *is* active, so the `\lowercase` instruction will produce an active `_`. The `\endgroup` will revert the `\lccode` assignment, but when the change to the lowercase counterpart has already been performed.