# How could LaTeX replace the tokens <= by the command \leq?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, parsing

How could LaTeX replace the tokens `<=` by the command `\leq` efficiently?

Example 1: I have this code:

```
\[
   2x <= 4x - 2
\]
```

And I want to get after the compilation this:

[image]

Example 2:

```
\[
     q --> q 
\]
```

Output:

[image]

Example 3:

```
\[
    Q ==> Q 
\]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This seems like more of an editor question to me - though you could call another program to parse the file before compiling.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Chris force of habit

Comment: possible things to look at: a) make `<` active and then test for `=` as the next input token; b) if both glyphs are in the same font (they're not, in computer modern), try a ligature (but i don't remember whether ligatures work in math mode; i think not).  i really don't recommend either method, but by investigating them, you'd probably learn something about tex's innards.

Comment: Well your 3rd example changes things a bit (assuming you want `\geq`=`=>` anyway.

Comment: Considering what Chris pointed out, this idea in general may have unintended and hard-to-debug side-effects.

Comment: I tend to do `\let\<\le` (and `let\<\ge`).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I assume, the replacements should be done in math mode only.
Then the starting characters can be made active via a special value `"8000` for `\mathcode`. The characters behave in text mode as usual, but they became special in math mode.

The following example document provides parsers for the following shorthands:

```
<< : \ll (latexsym/amsmath)
<> : \neq
<= : \leq
<== : \Leftarrow
<=> : \Leftrightarrow
<-- : \leftarrow
<-> : \leftrightarrow
>> : \gg (latexsym/amsmath)
>= : \geq
--> : \rightarrow
-+ : \pm
+- : \mp
... : \dots (amsmath)
== : \equiv
=. : \doteq
==> : \Rightarrow
=( : \subseteq (latexsym/amsmath)
=) : \supseteq (latexsym/amsmath)
=[ : \sqsubseteq (latexsym/amsmath)
=] : \sqsubseteq (latexsym/amsmath)
```

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{latexsym}
% * because of \gg, \ll, \subseteq, \supseteq, \sqsubseteq, \sqsupseteq
% * not needed if amsmath is loaded

\usepackage{amsmath}% because of \dots

\makeatletter
% LaTeX's \@ifnextchar gobbles spaces, therefore
% \msh@ifnextchar is defined that keeps spaces
\newcommand*{\msh@ifnextchar}[3]{%
  \def\msh@temp{\msh@@ifnextchar{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
  \futurelet\msh@token\msh@temp
}
\newcommand*{\msh@@ifnextchar}[1]{%
  \ifx\msh@token#1%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

% <<
% <>
% <=
% <==
% <=>
% <--
% <->
% >>
% >=
% -->
% -+
% +-
% ...
% ==
% =.
% ==>
% =(
% =)
% =[
% =]

% Commands that take the original meanings of the special characters
\mathchardef\msh@code@less=\mathcode`\<\relax
\mathchardef\msh@code@greater=\mathcode`\>\relax
\mathchardef\msh@code@minus=\mathcode`\-\relax
\mathchardef\msh@code@plus=\mathcode`\+\relax
\mathchardef\msh@code@equal=\mathcode`\=\relax
\mathchardef\msh@code@dot=\mathcode`\.\relax

% Macro \resetmathshorthands resets the original meaning of the
% special characters by resetting their \mathcode values
\@ifdefinable{\resetmathshorthands}{%
  \edef\resetmathshorthands{%
    \mathcode\number`\<=\msh@code@less
    \mathcode\number`\>=\msh@code@greater
    \mathcode\number`\-=\msh@code@minus
    \mathcode\number`\+=\msh@code@plus
    \mathcode\number`\.=\msh@code@dot
    \mathcode\number`\==\msh@code@equal
  }%
}

% Macro \setmathshorthands activates and defines the special
% characters
\begingroup
  \catcode`\<=\active
  \catcode`\>=\active
  \catcode`\-=\active
  \catcode`\+=\active
  \catcode`\.=\active
  \catcode`\==\active
  \edef={\string=}%
  \@ifdefinable{\setmathshorthands}{%
    \xdef\setmathshorthands{%
      \mathcode\number`\<="8000 %
      \mathcode\number`\>="8000 %
      \mathcode\number`\-="8000 %
      \mathcode\number`\+="8000 %
      \mathcode\number`\.="8000 %
      \mathcode\number`\=="8000 %
      \let\noexpand<\noexpand\msh@less
      \let\noexpand>\noexpand\msh@greater
      \let\noexpand-\noexpand\msh@minus
      \let\noexpand+\noexpand\msh@plus
      \let\noexpand.\noexpand\msh@dot
      \let\noexpand=\noexpand\msh@equal
    }%
  }%
\endgroup

% The parsers for the math shorthands follow:

% <<
% <>
% <=
% <==
% <=>
% <--
% <->
\newcommand*{\msh@less}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar<{%
    \ll\@gobble
  }{%
    \msh@ifnextchar>{%
      \neq\@gobble
    }{%
      \msh@ifnextchar={%
        \expandafter\msh@less@equal\@gobble
      }{%
        \msh@ifnextchar-{%
          \expandafter\msh@less@minus\@gobble
        }{%
          \msh@code@less
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\msh@less@equal}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar={%
    \Leftarrow\@gobble
  }{%
    \msh@ifnextchar>{%
      \Leftrightarrow\@gobble
    }{%
      \leq
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\msh@less@minus}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar-{%
    \leftarrow\@gobble
  }{%
    \msh@ifnextchar>{%
      \leftrightarrow\@gobble
    }{%
      \msh@code@less\msh@code@minus
    }%
  }%
}

% >>
% >=
\newcommand*{\msh@greater}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar>{%
    \gg\@gobble
  }{%
    \msh@ifnextchar={%
      \geq\@gobble
    }{%
      \msh@code@greater
    }%
  }%
}

% -->
% -+
\newcommand*{\msh@minus}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar-{%
    \expandafter\msh@minus@minus\@gobble
  }{%
    \msh@ifnextchar+{%
      \mp\@gobble
    }{%
      \msh@code@minus
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\msh@minus@minus}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar>{%
    \rightarrow\@gobble
  }{%
    \msh@code@minus\msh@code@minus
  }%
}

% +-
\newcommand*{\msh@plus}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar-{%
    \pm\@gobble
  }{%
    \msh@code@plus
  }%
}

% ...
\newcommand*{\msh@dot}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar.{%
    \expandafter\msh@dot@dot\@gobble
  }{%
    \msh@code@dot
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\msh@dot@dot}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar.{%
    \expandafter\msh@dot@dot@dot\@gobble
  }{%
    \msh@code@dot
    \msh@code@dot
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\msh@dot@dot@dot}{%
  % remove space after "...", because a space would
  % disturb \dots' auto-positioning feature.
  \expandafter\dots\romannumeral-`\x
}

% ==
% =.
% ==>
% =(
% =)
% =[
% =]
\newcommand*{\msh@equal}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar={%
    \expandafter\msh@equal@equal\@gobble
  }{%
    \msh@ifnextchar.{%
      \doteq\@gobble
    }{%
      \msh@ifnextchar({%
        \subseteq\@gobble
      }{%
        \msh@ifnextchar){%
          \supseteq\@gobble
        }{%
          \msh@ifnextchar[{%
            \sqsubseteq\@gobble
          }{%
            \msh@ifnextchar]{%
              \sqsupseteq\@gobble
            }{%
              \msh@code@equal
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\msh@equal@equal}{%
  \msh@ifnextchar>{%
    \Rightarrow\@gobble
  }{%
    \equiv
  }%
}
\makeatother

% Activate math shorthands in the math modes
\everymath{\setmathshorthands}
\everydisplay{\setmathshorthands}

\begin{document}
\centering
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  $#1$%
  \[#1\]%
}
\test{a << b < c <= d >= e > f >> g}
\test{a <> b = c =. d == e}
\test{a <== b <-- c <-> d <=> e --> f ==> g}
\test{a +- b = -(-a -+ +b)}
\test{a, ..., z <> a + ...+ z}
\test{a =( b =) c =[ e =] f}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- Macro `\msh@ifnextchar` looks up the next token. In opposite to LaTeX's `\@ifnextchar` it does not gobble spaces. For example, this is important for `a + -b` (*a - b*) that is different from `a +- b` (*a ± b*).
- `...` are replaced by `\dots` of package `amsmath`, because it has an auto-detection feature. The vertical position of the dots depends on the next token. For example, in a comma separated list, `\dots` become `\ldots`; if the next token is a `+`, then `\cdots` is used.

  Spaces are gobbled after a command token like `\dots`, but not after other characters like `...`. Therefore `\msh@dot@dot@dot` removes a following space before calling `\dots`. Otherwise `\dots` would see the space and become `\ldots`, even, if the token after the space is a `+`.
- The suggested `_C` for `\subseteq` looks too ambiguous too me, because it looks like a normal subscript `C`. Also there is not a good ASCII letter for use in the shorthand of `\supseteq`. Therefore I have implemented the shorthands `=(`, `=)` and the pair `=[`, `=]` for the square forms.

  If round or square parentheses follows the equal sign, then the shorthand replacement can be prevented by a space, e.g. `a = (b + c)`.

Comment: Undocumented feature: `< >` behaves differently than `<>` thanks to space-aware `ifnextchar`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Yes (poorly documented). It is also important for `a + -b` = `a - b` that is different from `a +- b` = `a \pm b`; answer updated.

Comment: How could I do that three dots (...) are replaced by \cdots and _C tokens by \subseteq?

Comment: Will you provide a new package?

Comment: @David: Done with some changes: `\dots` of package `amsmath` is more powerful than `\cdots`. Because `_C` looks too ambiguous too me, I have implemented the pairs `=(`/`=)` and `=[`/`=]`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel For that, I would say there would need to be a way to automate the replacements à la `listings`—different people have different ideas on what 'looks good' as ASCII math.  If I've learned anything of problem-solving, it'd be an interesting exercise in recursion.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Writing an example for a particular problem is one thing, writing a package that generalizes the problem another. A good package would have to answer, how to configure math shorthands and to add new ones.

Answer (score 14):

This is interesting problem which can be solved by more compact macros than in accepted answer:

```
\long\def\isnextchar#1#2#3{\begingroup\toks0={\endgroup#2}\toks1={\endgroup#3}%
   \let\tmp=#1\futurelet\next\isnextcharA
}
\def\isnextcharA{\the\toks\ifx\tmp\next0\else1\fi\space}

\def\skipnext#1#2{#1}    
\def\trynext#1{\trynextA#1\relax\relax}
\def\trynextA#1#2\relax#3\relax#4#5{%
   \ifx\relax#2\relax \def\next{\isnextchar#1{\skipnext{#4}}{#5#3}}\else
      \def\next{\isnextchar#1{\skipnext{\trynextA#2\relax#3#1\relax#4{#5}}}{#5#3}}\fi
   \next
}
\def\mspecdefA#1#2#3 : #4{\ifx#2\undefined
   \def#2{\trynext{#3}#4{#1}}\else
   \toks0={\trynext{#3}#4}\toks1=\expandafter{#2}%
   \edef#2{\the\toks0{\the\toks1}}\fi
}
\def\mspecdef#1{%
   \expandafter\ifx\csname m:#1\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\mathchardef\csname m:#1\endcsname=\mathcode`#1
   \fi
   \mathcode`#1="8000 
   \begingroup \lccode`~=`#1 
   \lowercase{\endgroup\expandafter\mspecdefA\csname m:#1\endcsname~}%
}

\mspecdef << : \ll
\mspecdef <> : \neq
\mspecdef <= : \leq
\mspecdef <== : \Leftarrow
\mspecdef <=> : \Leftrightarrow
\mspecdef <-- : \leftarrow
\mspecdef <-> : \leftrightarrow
\mspecdef >> : \gg
\mspecdef >= : \geq
\mspecdef --> : \rightarrow
\mspecdef -+ : \pm
\mspecdef +- : \mp
\mspecdef ... : \dots
\mspecdef == : \equiv
\mspecdef =. : \doteq
\mspecdef ==> : \Rightarrow
\mspecdef =( : \subseteq
\mspecdef =) : \supseteq
\mspecdef =[ : \sqsubseteq
\mspecdef =] : \sqsubseteq

test:

$$ a << b < c <= d >= e > f >> g $$
$$ a <> b = c =. d == e $$
$$ a <== b <-- c <-> d <=> e --> f ==> g $$
$$ a +- b = -(-a -+ +b) $$
$$ a, ..., z <> a + ...+ z $$
$$ a =( b =) c =[ e =] f $$

\bye
```

The result is the same as in accepted answer.

**Edit** How it works? When we do

```
\mspecdef ax : \U    \mspecdef axy : \V    \mspecdef abcd : \W
```

then the `a` character is set as math-active (i.e. `\matcode` is `"8000`) and it is defined as

```
\def a{\trynext{bcd}\W{\trynext{xy}\V{\trynext{x}\U{normal a}}}}
```

This macro does test if the following string is `bcd` (using repeatedly called `\isnextchar`). If it is true then next part of the macro is skipped and `\W` is processed. Else next part of the macro is processed. This means, that `xy` is tested. If fails then `x` is tested and if fails then normal `a` is printed.

We can do this only with TeX macros at primitive level without any non-TeX tools like lua code, without any obscure solutions like expl3.

Comment: `\pm` and `\mp` should be interchanged, I think.

Comment: @Manuel I copied only the introduction table from accepted answer and added the `\mspecdef` in each line.

Comment: Well, his implementation do them the other way around. In any case, I think it's common for `+-` to be plus-minus `\pm` and `-+` minus-plus `\mp`.

Comment: @Manuel This is not the main point of my interest. You can correct this in accepted answer and in my answer too. I aimed at something different: that this general feature can be done by simple TeX macros.

Comment: It was a minor thing, don't worry, I like this answer and upvoted it.

Comment: There is a small conflict with `amsmath`, `mathpartir` and `MnSymbol` when using this with LaTeX (not just plain TeX). The `\mspecdef` commands then simply need to be put after the `\begin{document}` or to be wrapped with `\AtBeginDocument{…}`.

Comment: I've packed it as a "package" from my point of view, i. e. the OPmac trick 0149 was created. http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#mspecdef

Answer (score 13):

The following is taken partially from [Define a command so that it is only active within the `document` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78746/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`<
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~{\@ifnextchar={\leq\@gobble}{<}}}%
  \catcode`<=\active
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$2x <= 4x - 2 \leq y$
\end{document}
```

But using an editor's search-and-replace seems just as appropriate.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It defines a Lua function, named `do_subs`, that performs substitutions on all the following two-letter and three-letter character combinations:

```
<== <=> ==> <= >= << >> <-- -->  -+ +- ... == <> =. =( =) =[ =]
```

By assigning this function to the "process_input_buffer" callback, the function acts as a pre-processor on the input stream -- TeX itself only ever sees and processes the corresponding math-mode macros.

Incidentally, it's assumed that these character combinations -- other than `...` -- will only ever occur in math mode. Do let me know if this assumption isn't warranted. (`...` gets replaced with `\dots`, and `\dots` can occur in both text and math mode.)

A comment on the Lua code: Since the characters `.`, `-`, `+`, `(`, `)`, `[`, and `]` are "special" in Lua search strings, they need to be escaped in order to lose the special meaning; this is done by prefixing `%` symbols to them. Fo instance, as `.` is the Lua "magic" character for *any character*, the pattern search string for `...` must be written as `%.%.%.`. (This is also why the code shown below encases the Lua function in a `luacode` environment; in such an environment, `%` is not treated as a comment character.)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for context-sensitive handling of `\dots` macro

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function do_subs ( buff )
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "<==",   "\\Leftarrow ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "<=>",   "\\Leftrightarrow ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "<=",    "\\leq ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "<<",    "\\ll ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "<%-%-", "\\leftarrow ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "<%->",  "\\leftrightarrow ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , ">>",    "\\gg ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , ">=",    "\\geq ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "%-%->", "\\rightarrow ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "%-%+",  "\\mp ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "%+%-",  "\\pm ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "%.%.%.","\\dots ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "=%.",   "\\doteq ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "==>",   "\\Rightarrow ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "==",    "\\equiv ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "<>",    "\\neq ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "=%(",   "\\subseteq ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "=%)",   "\\supseteq ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "=%[",   "\\sqsubseteq ")
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "=%]",   "\\sqsupseteq ")
  return buff
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
    "process_input_buffer" , do_subs, "do_subs" )}}

\begin{document}
$2x <= 4x - 2$

$<== <=> ==> <= >= << >> <-- -->  -+ +- ... == <> =. =( =) =[ =] $

\bigskip
$a << b < c <= d >= e > f >> g$

$a <> b = c =. d == e$

$a <== b <-- c <-> d <=> e --> f ==> g$

$a +- b = -(-a -+ +b)$

$a, ..., z <> a + ...+ z$

$a =( b =) c =[ e =] f$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This matches everywhere, not only in mathmode, right?

Comment: @HenriMenke - That's right. I noted in the answer that it's assumed that these character combinations will only ever occur in math mode. (However, it's OK for `\dots` to occur in text mode as well.) It's not too much extra work, actually, to add a test to check if the character combos occur inside or outside of math mode -- and to perform the substitutions only if a character combination occurs in math mode.

Comment: Is there no callback like `process_math_list` or so?

Comment: Ah, there is `mlist_to_hlist`.  Probably one could hook somehow into that.  I hope that nothing has been boxed at that point.

Answer (score 10):

While this solution doesn't maintain the air of 'mathiness,' it could be extremely useful for aspiring literate programmers.
The bonus?  No TeX hackery (that you see) and thus easily customizable!

Using the `listings` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,latexsym}

% Disclaimer: I don't actually know Pascal.  It's on my todo-list.
\lstset{language=Pascal}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[literate={<=}{{$\leq$}}1
                            {>=}{{$\geq$}}1
                            {!=}{{$\neq$}}1
                            {<==}{{$\Longleftarrow$}}2 % note this width was increased
                            {==>}{{$\Longrightarrow$}}2
                            {<<}{{$\ll$}}1 % the only need for `latexsym`
                            {+-}{{$\pm$}}1
                            {in}{{$\in$}}1] % and so on
  if x <= 5 do stuff();
  if x in {4 +- 2}
  stuff << st
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

ConTeXt has this funny `asciimath` module, which has unfortunately completely [different rules](http://asciimath.org/) (which are highly inconsistent), but it still fits the general task though.

Probably there is something about it in Hans' article [“When to stop ...”](https://www.tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb36-2/tb113hagen.pdf) which are the proceedings of his talk at TUG 2015, where he also mentioned `asciimath`.  (I've only seen the talk, the article is not free yet).

```
\usemodule[asciimath]

\starttext
$\asciimath{a << b < c <= d >= e > f >> g}$

$\asciimath{a <> b = c =. d == e}$

$\asciimath{a <== b <-- c <-> d <=> e --> f ==> g}$

$\asciimath{a +- b = -(-a -+ +b)}$

$\asciimath{a, ..., z <> a + ...+ z}$

$\asciimath{a =( b =) c =[ e =] f}$
\stoptext
```

[image]

Something similar can however be achieved in LaTeX using `expl3`.  Here we can also implement the correct substitutions.

With some trickery we can even make it automatic.  I do not recommend this though.  There are surely corner cases.  For example, it does not recurse subgroups.  To see what this means, try `\test{a =( {b =) c =[ e} =] f}` with the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_math_subs_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \math_add_sub:nn #1 #2
 {
   \seq_put_right:Nn \l_math_subs_seq { { #1 } { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \math_ascii_sub:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_math_subs_seq
   {
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl ##1
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \math_grabinline:w #1 $
 {
  \math_ascii_sub:n { #1 } $
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \math_grabdisplay:w #1 \]
 {
  \math_ascii_sub:n { #1 } \]
 }

% Set substitutions (be careful with order!)
% Three letter sequences first
\math_add_sub:nn { <== } { \Leftarrow }
\math_add_sub:nn { <=> } { \Leftrightarrow }
\math_add_sub:nn { <-- } { \leftarrow }
\math_add_sub:nn { <-> } { \leftrightarrow }
\math_add_sub:nn { --> } { \rightarrow }
\math_add_sub:nn { ==> } { \Rightarrow }
\math_add_sub:nn { ... } { \dots }
% Then two letter sequences
\math_add_sub:nn { << } { \ll  }
\math_add_sub:nn { <> } { \neq }
\math_add_sub:nn { <= } { \leq }
\math_add_sub:nn { >> } { \gg  }
\math_add_sub:nn { >= } { \geq }
\math_add_sub:nn { -+ } { \mp }
\math_add_sub:nn { +- } { \pm }
\math_add_sub:nn { == } { \equiv }
\math_add_sub:nn { =. } { \doteq }
\math_add_sub:nn { =( } { \subseteq }
\math_add_sub:nn { =) } { \supseteq }
\math_add_sub:nn { =[ } { \sqsubseteq }
\math_add_sub:nn { =] } { \sqsubseteq }

% Enable substitutions for $...$ and \[...\]
\everymath { \math_grabinline:w }
\tl_put_right:Nn \[ { \math_grabdisplay:w }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\centering
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  $#1$%
  \[#1\]%
}
\test{a << b < c <= d >= e > f >> g}
\test{a <> b = c =. d == e}
\test{a <== b <-- c <-> d <=> e --> f ==> g}
\test{a +- b = -(-a -+ +b)}
\test{a, ..., z <> a + ...+ z}
\test{a =( b =) c =[ e =] f}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to be careful to change before `==>` and then `==`. If you change the other way around you get unwanted symbols. An option is to change them with a space `{ ~==~ }` and `{ ~==>~ }` (and the same for the rest), that way there's no problem.

Comment: @Manuel The additional spaces might gain you *some* safety, but do not rectify the issue that this in general a bad idea.

Comment: In the screenshot, each line appears to be in duplicate. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mico Yes: `\newcommand*{\test}[1]{$#1$\[#1\]}` (like in Heiko's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here I do it with `listofitems` parsing, though it had some difficulty when separators shared identical sequences (such as `<==` and `<=`), so I had to manually nest the parsings of 3-char and 2-char separator sequences.  Even so, the coding is quite compact.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,amsmath}
\newcommand\mnemonic[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname\detokenize{#1x}\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\test[1]{$%
  \setsepchar{...||<==||<=>||<--||<->||-->||==>}%
  \readlist\zlist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\zlist{%
    \setsepchar{==||<<||<=||>>||>=||-+||+-||=.||=(||=)||=[||=]||<>}%
    \readlist\zzlist{\z}%
    \foreachitem\zz\in\zzlist{%
      \zz
      \csname\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        {\zzlistsep[\zzcnt]x}\endcsname
    }
    \csname\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\zlistsep[\zcnt]x}\endcsname
  }
  $\par}
\mnemonic{<<}{\ll}
\mnemonic{<>}{\neq}
\mnemonic{<=}{\leq}
\mnemonic{<==}{\Leftarrow}
\mnemonic{<=>}{\Leftrightarrow}
\mnemonic{<--}{\leftarrow}
\mnemonic{<->}{\leftrightarrow}
\mnemonic{>>}{\gg}
\mnemonic{>=}{\geq}
\mnemonic{-->}{\rightarrow}
\mnemonic{-+}{\pm}
\mnemonic{+-}{\mp}
\mnemonic{...}{\dots}
\mnemonic{==}{\equiv}
\mnemonic{=.}{\doteq}
\mnemonic{==>}{\Rightarrow}
\mnemonic{=(}{\subseteq}
\mnemonic{=)}{\supseteq}
\mnemonic{=[}{\sqsubseteq}
\mnemonic{=]}{\sqsubseteq}
\begin{document}
\test{a << b < c <= d >= e > f >> g}
\test{a <> b = c =. d == e}
\test{a <== b <-- c <-> d <=> e --> f ==> g}
\test{a +- b = -(-a -+ +b)}
\test{a, ..., z <> a + ...+ z}
\test{a =( b =) c =[ e =] f}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is impossibile that you have 0 score after a long and very nice code.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you.  I just posted it and it had a popular accepted answer, so I didn't expect much.  I just really enjoy using certain packages: `listofitems`, `tokcycle`, and of course, `[tab]stackengine`.