# Include a package in one chapter only

Tags: header-footer, packages, chapters, fancyhdr

I have this package that removes the header from the pages

```
 \fancypagestyle{noheadrule}{  \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} }
    \pagestyle{noheadrule}
```

It works like a charm but i only want to use it in one chapter but it removes all the headers from all the pages of the project

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How about using `pagestyle{fancy}` or `pagestyle{plain}` for the other chapters? ;-) Or defining a pagestyle `\fancypagestyle{headrule}`, that does not set `\headrulewidth` to `0pt`?

Comment: Please edit your question title. I think this is about how to change pagestyle (from chapter to another)

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to include a package for one chapter and 'unload' it for another part of the document.

However, it's possible to limit the effects what a chapter does, depending on the chapter.

Explicitly define two different pagestyles, one for the particular chapter and another one, that restores the settings (or changes them to something other!)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}



\fancypagestyle{headrule}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}  
  \fancyhead[CE]{foo}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} 
}

\fancypagestyle{noheadrule}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} 
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{noheadrule}
\chapter{The one with no headrule}
\blindtext[15]


\clearpage
\pagestyle{headrule}
\chapter{The fancy one!}
\blindtext[15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, congrats on joining the ranks of the "Legendary"!! Just noticed that it happened a few days ago.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, it was a long journey to this badge ;-) Alas, it will be the last Gold badge for a long time

Comment: You made it "legendary" status in about half as much time as it took me! Your many contributions on this site are much appreciated.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks again ;-) Because you gave too much `lua` - based answers? ;-)

Comment: Indeed, LuaLaTeX-based answers don't tend to generate a lot of upvotes... :-) I fear Lua(La)TeX is still a few -- but hopefully not many -- years away from experiencing more widespread adoption by the masses.

Comment: @Mico: Sounds like a world-domination plan ;-) and I always upvote them -- I don't understand them, but I upvote them (if I spot your answers ;-))

Comment: Awwwww. :-) You're too kind! Much appreciated, for sure!!

Comment: I'm giving you another chance to do a good deed: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311485/5001 :-)

Comment: @Mico: ;-) ;-) ;-) ;-)