# \tl_replace_all:Nnn recurse subgroups

Tags: expl3, latex3, grouping

Suppose I had a token list variable containing  `abc{ab{abc}c}`.  I want to replace every occurrence of `b` with `d`.   As you can see there are subgroups containing `b` which I also want to have replaced, so a simple

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { abc{ab{abc}c} }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { b } { d }
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

won't do, as the result is `adc{ab{abc}c}` (only the `b` in the outermost grouping level was replaced).

One might attempt to grab the first level of grouping by mapping the token list à la

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_tmpc_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { abc{ab{abc}c} }
% iterate all tokens
\tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl
 {
  % obtain sub token list
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { #1 }
  % replace
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpb_tl { b } { d }
  % append to result
  \tl_put_right:NV \l_tmpc_tl \l_tmpb_tl
 }
\tl_show:N \l_tmpc_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this only acts on the first level and has the undesired side-effect of completely losing that level, as the result of this is `adcad{abc}c`.

How can I do a *recursive* search and replace *without* losing grouping?  (Bonus for full expandability!)

---

I hope this simple example does not lose any generality.

Comment: Of course a bounty will be offered.

Comment: Isn't this a job for `l3regex`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I haven't used `l3regex` before.  I am happy to read your answer using it.

Comment: `\regex_replace_all:nnN` is here for this purpose. In any case, I think they actually do something similar for `\tl_(lower|upper)_case:nn` so you might want to look at the implementation until an answer arrives.

Comment: @Manuel: I think that `\regex_replace_all:nnN` does something similar internally what Henri tried to achieve with the `\tl_map_inline`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, that's what I would use, but I didn't know he was not aware of `l3regex` so I thought he was trying to solve it without that, hence my proposal of looking into `\tl_.._case:nn`. *I think* `l3regex` does internally by `\detokenize`ing the token list, then doing replacements.

Comment: @Manuel It would actually be awesome, if one could do it with an approach similar to `\tl_..._case:n`, because these are fully expandable.

Comment: Replacing tokens in a variable necessarily does an assignment which never is expandable.

Comment: @clemens I though about it like this: `\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_upper_case:n { abc } }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need full expandable solution of replacing text including text in groups, here is an idea:

```
\def\repl#1{\replA #1{\end}}
\def\replA#1#{\replB#1\end}
\def\replB#1{\ifx\end#1\expandafter\replC \else\replX{#1}\expandafter\replB\fi}
\def\replC#1{\ifx\end#1\empty\else{\repl{#1}}\expandafter\replA\fi}
\def\replX#1{\ifx#1bd\else#1\fi}

\message{....\repl{abc{aabc{bb}}cb}}

\bye
```

The `\message` command expands its argument and prints: `....adc{aadc{dd}}cd`.

This code ignores spaces between tokens. The space handling was not specified in your task. If you need to keep spaces unchanged then the code needs to be a slight more complicated (about five more lines).

**Edit** My estimation was not exact. The code which accepts spaces needs only three more lines:

```
\def\repl#1{\replA #1{\end}}
\def\replA#1#{\replD#1 {\end} }
\def\replD#1 #2 {\replB#1\end
   \ifx\end#2\expandafter\replC\else\space\fihere\replD#2 \fi}
\def\replB#1{\ifx\end#1\else\replX{#1}\expandafter\replB\fi}
\def\replC#1{\ifx\end#1\empty\else{\repl{#1}}\expandafter\replA\fi}
\def\replX#1{\ifx#1bd\else#1\fi}
\def\fihere#1\fi{\fi#1}

\message{....\repl{ab c{ aa bc {bb}}cb}}

\bye
```

Comment: I admire your skill in writing so concise and short macros!

Comment: But isn't it a little dangerous to use `\end` as a delimiter?  What if it gets expanded by accident?

Comment: Hm.  I just noticed that this is limited to a one-to-one token replacement.  It would be great to be able to replace substrings of several tokens.

Comment: @HenriMenke At least there's a requirement that you need to define with a symbolic name such kind of replacement. Like `\definerepl{name}{foo}{bar} \edef\tmp{\repl{name}{foo{foo{foo}}}}`.

Comment: @Manuel No, You can do fully expandable string comparison in pdftex using `pdfstrcmp`.

Comment: @HenriMenke But how do you know what to “grab”. How do you know (easily) that `\repl{henrimenke}{here}{it would work henrimenke?}`, you definitely need some sort of `\def\foo#1henrimenke#2\end{#1here#2}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I'd mistakenly assumed you wanted an `expl3` solution. But I guess I never really understood the question. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @cfr No!  Your answer is of very high quality and is a good example of how to have non-expandable recursive replacing in `expl3`.

Comment: @HenriMenke in wipet's world, `\end` is a non-expandable primitive:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True ;) But what if you hit it and it is *executed* (that's what I meant, not expanded)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is irrelevant where is my world. The processing fails if `\end` is executed as primitive (unwanted end of all processing) or \end is expanded (another curious bug). But `\end` is not executed nor expanded in my macros:).

Comment: @wipet yes I know! it was just a flippant reply to Henri's comment  not really about your macros at all, but I'll delete it (and this comment) in  a bit:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please, don't delete your comments. It is enjoyable to read about different worlds:)

Answer (score 8):

While Manuel was commenting, I remembered `\regex_replace_all:nnN`, where the first argument contains the token to be replaced by the 2nd argument in the token variable given as 3rd. argument.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{l3regex}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { abc{ab{abc}c} }

Before:\space \l_tmpa_tl \par

\regex_replace_all:nnN  {b} {d} \l_tmpa_tl

After:\space \l_tmpa_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While `l3regex` surely works, it makes it hard to replace strings containing many special characters, because each of the has to be escaped.

Comment: @HenriMenke It's not that difficult, in my opinion. Could you give an example? And, by the way, why putting the code on an external webpage?

Comment: @HenriMenke: Well, I am waiting for a use case then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer See [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311480/10995), where I have weird replacements to do like `=[` → `\sqsubseteq`.

Comment: @Manuel See comment to Christian.  I didn't want to clutter the question with irrelevant code.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I see -- well, that's  nothing I can attack quickly.

Comment: @HenriMenke How can a minimal example required to understand the question be irrelevant code?

Comment: @HenriMenke  `\regex_replace_all:nnN { =[ } { \c{sqsubseteq} } \l_tmpa_tl`

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is what you mean now I've seen your discussion in comments, but it certainly works for the cases in the original question.

This code does not rely on any package or code explicitly designated as experimental by the L3 developers.

Note, however, that I have no idea what I am doing.

## *Caveat emptor ....*

Counts are included to show that the grouping within the token lists is preserved e.g. that `a{bcde}f` is counted as 3 tokens and not 6 or 8 when the token list is reassembled. During processing, the *string* is obviously counted as having more tokens since this is necessary to search and replace within the groups.

The result of the replacement operation is stored in a globally set variable `\g_henri_mod_tl`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \l_henri_mod_str
\int_new:N \l_henri_tmpa_int
\int_new:N \l_henri_tmpb_int
\int_new:N \l_henri_tmpc_int
\tl_new:N \g_henri_mod_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \henri_replace_all:nnn #1 #2 #3
{
  \group_begin:
    \str_clear:N \l_henri_mod_str
    \int_zero:N \l_henri_tmpa_int
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { #1 }
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpb_str { #2 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_henri_tmpb_int { \str_count:N \l_tmpa_str }
    \int_set:Nn \l_henri_tmpc_int { \str_count:N \l_tmpb_str }
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_henri_tmpc_int = 1 }
    {
      \int_do_until:nn { \l_henri_tmpb_int = \l_henri_tmpa_int }
      {
        \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { #2 } { \str_head:N \l_tmpa_str }
        {
          \str_put_right:Nx \l_henri_mod_str { #3 }
        }
        {
          \str_put_right:Nx \l_henri_mod_str { \str_head:N \l_tmpa_str }
        }
        \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \str_tail:N \l_tmpa_str }
        \int_incr:N \l_henri_tmpa_int
      }
    }
    {
      \int_do_until:nn { \l_henri_tmpb_int = \l_henri_tmpa_int }
      {
        \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { #2 } { \str_range:Nnn \l_tmpa_str { 1 } { \l_henri_tmpc_int } }
        {
          \str_put_right:Nx \l_henri_mod_str { #3 }
          \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \str_count:N \l_tmpa_str }
          \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \str_range:Nnn \l_tmpa_str { 1 + \l_henri_tmpc_int } { \l_tmpa_int } }
          \int_add:Nn \l_henri_tmpa_int { \l_henri_tmpc_int }
        }
        {
          \str_put_right:Nx \l_henri_mod_str { \str_head:N \l_tmpa_str }
          \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \str_tail:N \l_tmpa_str }
          \int_incr:N \l_henri_tmpa_int
        }
      }
    }
    \tl_gset_rescan:Nno \g_henri_mod_tl {} { \l_henri_mod_str }
  \group_end:
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \henri_replace_all:nnn { Vnn }

\henri_replace_all:nnn { abc{ab{abc}c} } { b } { d }
\g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { abc{ab{abc}c} }
\henri_replace_all:Vnn \l_tmpa_tl { b } { d }
\g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\henri_replace_all:nnn { {a=b}\,{[]} } { [ } { \sqsubseteq }
$\g_henri_mod_tl$ {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\henri_replace_all:nnn { gydihŵs } { y } { w }
\g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\henri_replace_all:nnn { abc{ab{abc}c} } { bc } { doodle }
\g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\henri_replace_all:nnn { {a=[b}\,{[]} } { =[ } { \sqsubseteq }
$\g_henri_mod_tl$ {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image: token list manipulation]

**EDITED** to deal with searches for strings of more than one character. This can correctly substitute `=[` with `\sqsubseteq` as mentioned [in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311699/tl-replace-allnnn-recurse-subgroups#comment758040_311700).

## EDIT

It is possible to define a further command sequence which obeys the target syntax. However, it should be noticed that this will not work in all cases. In particular, it fails to work correctly with gwdihŵs.

The idea is just to do the replacement and then spit out the global variable. I am not sure that it is correct to call the macro `\tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn` as this lacks any appropriate prefix, but if the macro is for purely personal use and you're not worried about future breakage, that's up to you. Personally, I'd call it something like `\henri_replace_allrecursive:nnn` and be safe since I don't see anything to be gained from violating the naming rules.

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn #1 #2 #3
{
  \henri_replace_all:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  \g_henri_mod_tl
}
```

Then we can say

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn { abc{ab{abc}c} } { b } { d } }
\l_tmpa_tl \par

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn { {a=b}\,{[]} } { [ } { \sqsubseteq }  }
$\l_tmpa_tl$ \par

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn { abc{ab{abc}c} } { bc } { doodle } }
\l_tmpa_tl \par
%
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn { {a=[b}\,{[]} } {  =[ } { \sqsubseteq } }
$\l_tmpa_tl$ \par
```

and, comparing with the original results, we can see that the replacements are as expected (less gwdihŵs, of course).

[image: comparison]

I take it the count of tokens here is irrelevant since everything is being expanded.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \l_henri_mod_str
\int_new:N \l_henri_tmpa_int
\int_new:N \l_henri_tmpb_int
\int_new:N \l_henri_tmpc_int
\tl_new:N \g_henri_mod_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \henri_replace_all:nnn #1 #2 #3
{
  \group_begin:
    \str_clear:N \l_henri_mod_str
    \int_zero:N \l_henri_tmpa_int
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { #1 }
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpb_str { #2 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_henri_tmpb_int { \str_count:N \l_tmpa_str }
    \int_set:Nn \l_henri_tmpc_int { \str_count:N \l_tmpb_str }
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_henri_tmpc_int = 1 }
    {
      \int_do_until:nn { \l_henri_tmpb_int = \l_henri_tmpa_int }
      {
        \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { #2 } { \str_head:N \l_tmpa_str }
        {
          \str_put_right:Nx \l_henri_mod_str { #3 }
        }
        {
          \str_put_right:Nx \l_henri_mod_str { \str_head:N \l_tmpa_str }
        }
        \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \str_tail:N \l_tmpa_str }
        \int_incr:N \l_henri_tmpa_int
      }
    }
    {
      \int_do_until:nn { \l_henri_tmpb_int = \l_henri_tmpa_int }
      {
        \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { #2 } { \str_range:Nnn \l_tmpa_str { 1 } { \l_henri_tmpc_int } }
        {
          \str_put_right:Nx \l_henri_mod_str { #3 }
          \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \str_count:N \l_tmpa_str }
          \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \str_range:Nnn \l_tmpa_str { 1 + \l_henri_tmpc_int } { \l_tmpa_int } }
          \int_add:Nn \l_henri_tmpa_int { \l_henri_tmpc_int }
        }
        {
          \str_put_right:Nx \l_henri_mod_str { \str_head:N \l_tmpa_str }
          \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \str_tail:N \l_tmpa_str }
          \int_incr:N \l_henri_tmpa_int
        }
      }
    }
    \tl_gset_rescan:Nno \g_henri_mod_tl {} { \l_henri_mod_str }
  \group_end:
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \henri_replace_all:nnn { Vnn }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn #1 #2 #3
{
  \henri_replace_all:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  \g_henri_mod_tl
}

\verb|\henri_replace_all:nnn {  } {  } {  } \g_henri_mod_tl|
\smallskip\par

\henri_replace_all:nnn { abc{ab{abc}c} } { b } { d }
\g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { abc{ab{abc}c} }
\henri_replace_all:Vnn \l_tmpa_tl { b } { d }
\g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\henri_replace_all:nnn { {a=b}\,{[]} } { [ } { \sqsubseteq }
$\g_henri_mod_tl$ {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\henri_replace_all:nnn { gydihŵs } { y } { w }
\g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\henri_replace_all:nnn { abc{ab{abc}c} } { bc } { doodle }
\g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\henri_replace_all:nnn { {a=[b}\,{[]} } { =[ } { \sqsubseteq }
$\g_henri_mod_tl$ {} ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \g_henri_mod_tl {} ~ tokens.\par

\bigskip\par
\verb|\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn { ... } { ... } { ... } }|
\smallskip\par

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn { abc{ab{abc}c} } { b } { d } }
\l_tmpa_tl \par

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn { {a=b}\,{[]} } { [ } { \sqsubseteq }  }
$\l_tmpa_tl$ \par

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn { abc{ab{abc}c} } { bc } { doodle } }
\l_tmpa_tl \par
%
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_replace_allrecursive:nnn { {a=[b}\,{[]} } {  =[ } { \sqsubseteq } }
$\l_tmpa_tl$ \par


\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: In terms of 'why not in `expl3`: we've not needed it for our work, and likely will aim to avoid such things :-) (We do have an expandable set up for replacing material, used in for example case changing, and that is probably more 'interesting', plus there is `l3regex` for tricky cases.)

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the information. Were you responding to something I said?

Comment: @JosephWright I'm still confused by your comment.

Comment: @JosephWright I was thinking of providing an expandable replacement like `\tl_replacement_new:nnn { name } { search } { replace }` and then `\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_replacement_use:nn { name } { search and destroy } }` which would expand to `replace and destroy`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's (hopefully) a working fully expandable solution with expl3. It's `f`-expandable, and, of course, `x`-expandable.

This solution provides three commands

```
\setfreplace{name}{search}{replace}
\freplace{name}{token list where one wants to search}
\hmenke_tl_replace_nested:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { search } { replace }
```

Once certain replacement is defined, the `\freplace` will search and replace recursively inside of braces and will return the token list already replaced within `\unexpanded` so it won't expand further in `\edef`. `\hmenke_tl_replace_nested:Nnn` works as expected.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_generate_variant:Nn { c }

\NewDocumentCommand \setfreplace { m +m +m }
 {
  \hmenke_set_freplace:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \freplace { +m +m }
 {
  \hmenke_freplace:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\quark_new:N \q_hmenke
\cs_new:Npn \hmenke_freplace:nn #1 #2
 {
  \exp_not:f { \use:c { hmenke_freplace_#1:n } { #2 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \hmenke_set_freplace:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \cs_set:cpx { hmenke_freplace_#1:n } ##1
   {
    \exp_not:c { hmenke_freplace_#1_auxi:nw } { } ##1 { \exp_not:N \q_hmenke }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { hmenke_freplace_#1_auxi:nw } ##1 ##2 ##
   {
    \exp_not:c { hmenke_freplace_#1_nobraces:nfn }
     { ##1 } { \exp_not:c { hmenke_freplace_#1_do:n } { ##2 } }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { hmenke_freplace_#1_nobraces:nnn } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:c { hmenke_freplace_#1_auxii:nn } { ##1 ##2 }
   }
  \cs_generate_variant:cn { hmenke_freplace_#1_nobraces:nnn } { nf }
  \cs_set:cpx { hmenke_freplace_#1_auxii:nn } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:N \str_if_eq:nnTF { \exp_not:N \q_hmenke } { ##2 }
     { \exp_stop_f: ##1 }
     {
      \exp_not:c { hmenke_freplace_#1_addbraces:nfw }
       { ##1 } { \exp_not:c { hmenke_freplace_#1:n } { ##2 } }
     }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { hmenke_freplace_#1_addbraces:nnw } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:c { hmenke_freplace_#1_auxi:nw } { ##1 { ##2 } }
   }
  \cs_generate_variant:cn { hmenke_freplace_#1_addbraces:nnw } { nf }
  \cs_set:cpx { hmenke_freplace_#1_do:n } ##1
   {
    \exp_not:N \tl_if_empty:nTF { ##1 }
     { \exp_stop_f: }
     {
      \exp_not:c { hmenke_freplace_#1_auxiii:nww }
       { } ##1 \exp_not:n { #2 \q_hmenke \q_stop }
     }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { hmenke_freplace_#1_auxiii:nww } ##1 ##2 #2 ##3 \q_stop
   {
    \exp_not:N \str_if_eq:nnTF { \exp_not:N \q_hmenke } { ##3 }
     { \exp_stop_f: ##1 ##2 }
     {
      \exp_not:c { hmenke_freplace_#1_auxiii:nww }
       { ##1 ##2 \exp_not:n { #3 } } ##3 \exp_not:N \q_stop
     }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hmenke_freplace:nn { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \hmenke_tl_replace_nested:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \hmenke_set_freplace:nnn { _hmenke_ } { #2 } { #3 }
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \hmenke_freplace:nV { _hmenke_ } #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setfreplace{wipet}{b}{d}
\setfreplace{cfr1}{[}{\sqsubseteq}
\setfreplace{cfr2}{y}{w}
\setfreplace{cfr3}{bc}{doodle}
\setfreplace{cfr4}{=[}{\sqsubseteq}
\setfreplace{style}{\textbf}{\textsf}


\begin{document}

%%% For this particular example to show the \detokenize of the f-expanded \freplace
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \fdetokenize { } { \exp_args:Nf \tl_to_str:n }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%

\newcommand*\test[3][]{\par\medskip
  edef: \edef\tmp{\freplace{#2}{#3}}\meaning\tmp\par
  detokenize: \fdetokenize{\freplace{#2}{#3}}\par
  output: #1\tmp#1\par}

\test{wipet}{ab c{ aa bc {bb}}cb}
\test[$]{cfr1}{{a=b}\,{[]}}
\test{cfr2}{gydihŵs}
\test{cfr3}{abc{ab{abc}c}}
\test[$]{cfr4}{{a=[b}\,{[]}}
\test{style}{this is \textbf{boldface}, {or {is it {\textbf{sans} serif}?}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { abc{ab{abc}c} }
\hmenke_tl_replace_nested:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { b } { d }
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

---

Here it is with a different way of calling it, may be more natural, that doesn't rely on symbolic names. You “define” the replacement with

```
\setfreplace{search}{replace}
```

and then call it with `\freplace{search}{replace}{string to search text}`, which might be more natural

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_generate_variant:Nn { c }

\NewDocumentCommand \setfreplace { +m +m }
 {
  \freplace_set:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \freplace { +m +m +m }
 {
  \freplace:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\quark_new:N \q_freplace
\quark_new:N \q_freplacestop
\cs_new:Npn \freplace:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \exp_not:f { \use:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } ):n } { #3 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \freplace_set:nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } ):n } ##1
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxi:nw } { } ##1 { \exp_not:N \q_freplace }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxi:nw } ##1 ##2 ##
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_nobraces:nfn }
     { ##1 } { \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_do:n } { ##2 } }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_nobraces:nnn } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxii:nn } { ##1 ##2 }
   }
  \cs_generate_variant:cn { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_nobraces:nnn } { nf }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxii:nn } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:N \str_if_eq:nnTF { \exp_not:N \q_freplace } { ##2 }
     { \exp_stop_f: ##1 }
     {
      \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_addbraces:nfw }
       { ##1 } { \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } ):n } { ##2 } }
     }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_addbraces:nnw } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxi:nw } { ##1 { ##2 } }
   }
  \cs_generate_variant:cn { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_addbraces:nnw } { nf }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_do:n } ##1
   {
    \exp_not:N \tl_if_empty:nTF { ##1 }
     { \exp_stop_f: }
     {
      \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxiii:nww }
       { } ##1 \exp_not:n { #1 \q_freplace \q_freplacestop }
     }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxiii:nww } ##1 ##2 #1 ##3 \q_freplacestop
   {
    \exp_not:N \str_if_eq:nnTF { \exp_not:N \q_freplace } { ##3 }
     { \exp_stop_f: ##1 ##2 }
     {
      \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxiii:nww }
       { ##1 ##2 \exp_not:n { #2 } } ##3 \exp_not:N \q_freplacestop
     }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \freplace:nnn { nnV }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tl_replace_nested:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \freplace_set:nn { #2 } { #3 }
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \freplace:nnV { #2 } { #3 } #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setfreplace{ }{}
\setfreplace{b}{d}
\setfreplace{\textbf}{\textsf}


\begin{document}

%%% For this particular example to show the \detokenize of the f-expanded \freplace
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \fdetokenize { } { \exp_args:Nf \tl_to_str:n }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\test[3]{\par\fdetokenize{\freplace{#1}{#2}{#3}}\par}
%%%

\test{b}{d}{ab c{ aa bc {bb}}cb}
\test{ }{}{string to {be removed} {of {spaces }}}
\test{\textbf}{\textsf}{this is \textbf{boldface}, {or {is it {\textbf{sans} serif}?}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { abc{ab{abc}c} }
\tl_replace_nested:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { b } { d }
\tl_to_str:N \l_tmpa_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a somewhat-general solution to [manipulate tl as list of tokens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/393462/250119), the `analysis` family of expl3 functions can be used.

Alternatives

- `l3regex` can be used too, but internally it uses `peek_analysis_map_inline` anyway.
- `tokcycle` is also good, but it does not support [getting charcode of `{}` directly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/628358/250119) (as far as I can see.).

(also, for rebuilding the token list, to deal with the fact that the intermediate value may be unbalanced, the approach is to store e.g. `\iffalse { \else } \fi` into it then x-expand the thing. Which is also the approach of `l3regex`)

There's a slight disadvantage however, that the result will not be expandable.

---

The actual code:

```
\def \f #1 {
    \tl_build_begin:N \a
    \tl_analysis_map_inline:nn {#1} {
        \int_compare:nNnTF {##2} = {`b} {
            \tl_build_put_right:Nn \a {d}
        } {
            \tl_build_put_right:Nn \a {##1}
        }
    }
    \tl_build_end:N \a
    \tl_set:Nx \a {\a}
}
```

Takes input as `#1`, store result into `\a`.

<sub>needless to say, in real code don't redefine important LaTeX macros such as `\f`, `\a` etc.</sub>