# How to write a command to format different letters?

Tags: macros, programming

I hope I can have a command `MyFormatter`, which can make letters `p` and `k` bold and make letters `m` and `t` italic.

For example:

```
\MyFormatter{Supermarket}
```

will output as follows:

> Su**p**er*m*ar**k**e*t*

How to write the command `\MyFormatter` in LaTeX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution using expl3. If you need it to work in subgroups `\MyFormatter{Supermarket and \MakeUppercase{Supermarket}}` you can check [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313585/21930).

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \myformatter { +m } { \xmllmx_myformatter:n { #1 } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xmllmx_myformatter:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { p } { \textbf{p} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { k } { \textbf{k} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { m } { \textit{m} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { t } { \textit{t} }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Answer (score 6):

It's easy and flexible with regular expressions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myformatter}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([kp]+) } { \c{textbf}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} }
   \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([mt]+) } { \c{textit}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} }
   \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myformatter{Supermarket}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An approach using catcodes that works if the `\MyFormatter` appears in the clear and is not part of an argument.  As egreg pointed out in this regard, `\mbox{\MyFormatter{Supermarket}}` fails.

However, I jokingly retort in my comment that the way to get around the fail-case is to put the `\mbox` inside the `MyFormatter`, not the other way around.  Of course, the new drawback with this "fix" is that the "m" of `\mbox` is now active, and so an additional `\let` is required:  `\let\MBOX\mbox\MyFormatter{\MBOX{Supermarket}}`.

Finally, wipet comments that one could argue that the problem lies in the definition of `\mbox`, in that `\hbox{\MyFormatter{Supermarket}}` does not suffer the same problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\BB\textbf
\let\II\textit
\let\CC\catcode
\let\AC\active
\let\SVP p \let\SVK k \let\SVM m \let\SVT t
\def\CODESON{\CC`p=\AC  \CC`k=\AC  \CC`m=\AC  \CC`t=\AC }
\def\CODESOFF{\CC`p=11 \CC`k=11 \CC`m=11 \CC`t=11 }
\CODESON
\def p{\BB{\SVP}}
\def k{\BB{\SVK}}
\def m{\II{\SVM}}
\def t{\II{\SVT}}
\CODESOFF
\newcommand\MF[1]{#1\CODESOFF}
\newcommand\MyFormatter{\CODESON\MF}
\begin{document}
Supermarket \MyFormatter{Supermarket} Supermarket

\mbox{\MyFormatter{Supermarket}} fails, but

\let\MBOX\mbox\MyFormatter{\MBOX{Supermarket}} works
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\mbox{\MyFormatter{Supermarket}}`

Comment: @egreg DRAT!  Again, I say DRAT!

Comment: @egreg Of course, since `\MyFormatter{Supermarket}` doesn't hyphenate, why would one need to put it into an `\mbox`?  `;^)`

Comment: And of course, you are using the wrong syntax!  Clearly, it is:  `\let\MB\mbox\MyFormatter{\MB{Supermarket}}`.  Isn't that obvious?? `8^b`

Comment: But `\hbox{\MyFormater{Supermarket}}` works. This is LaTeX problem that `\mbox` is defined as macro with parameter. It needs not.

Comment: @wipet I know you are aware of the differerence between `\hbox` and `\mbox` (with parameter or not, that's a different topic). LaTeX users aren't and advertising `\hbox` is not the best service to them. Besides, `\mbox` was just an example; any command with argument would suffer of the same problem, including plain TeX ones.

Comment: Advertising `\hbox` is best service to them because they come to know that there are other approaches than only LaTeX. :-). Or they can define `\def\mbox{\leavevmode\hbox}`

Answer (score 2):

For example using OPmac:

```
\input opmac

\def\MyFormatter{\afterassignment\MyFormatterA \def\tmpb}
\def\MyFormatterA{\replacestrings{p}{{\bf p}}\replacestrings{k}{{\bf k}}%
   \replacestrings{m}{{\it m}\/}\replacestrings{t}{{\it t}\/}\tmpb}

\MyFormatter{Supermarket}

\bye
```