# Creating commands with formatted names in \csname\endcsname

Tags: macros, expansion

I am trying to create a method `MakeCommands` which will generate a couple of commands based on the basic name passed as a parameter. However, I want the user to be allowed to pass a name with spaces, which therefore must be extracted from the passed parameter for use as actual function names

What I currently have (creating just one command, for simplicity's sake) is:

```
\newcommand*{\MakeCommand}[1]
{
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{TEST}
}
```

This works, in that a call such as `\MakeCommand{Bday}` creates the command `\theBday` which expands to `TEST`. However, if the parameter is actually multiple words (`\MakeCommand{Date of Birth}`), then created command would have to be called using `\csname theDate of Birth\endcsname`, which isn't very elegant.

So I tried the following:

```
% \usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand*{\temp}{}
\newcommand*{\MakeCommand}[1]
{
    \renewcommand*{\temp}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{}}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname the\temp\endcsname{TEST}
}
```

Basically, use `xstring`'s `StrSubstitute` command to extract the spaces from the passed parameter and store it in `\temp`. And then use this spaceless version of the parameter as the command name.

This, however, doesn't work and I get multiple errors. For instance, for the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\temp}{}
\newcommand*{\MakeCommand}[1]
{
    \renewcommand*{\temp}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{}}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname the\temp \endcsname{TEST}
    %\expandafter\newcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{TEST}
}
\MakeCommand{Date of Birth}

\begin{document}
    \theDateofBirth
\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. \MakeCommand{Date of Birth}
Command \the already defined. \MakeCommand{Date of Birth}
Extra \endcsname. \MakeCommand{Date of Birth}
Missing \begin{document}. \MakeCommand{Date of Birth}
Undefined control sequence. ^^I\theDateofBirth
```

If I comment out the `\expandafter...` line and replace `\theDateofBirth` inside the document contents with `\temp`, the file compiles just fine and outputs "DateofBirth", as expected.

I can tell from other readings ([[A]](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf), [[B]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451/54852), [[C]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320933/54852)) that this probably requires additional `\expandafter`s, but I can't for the life of me figure out where to put them and why/how.

---

This is for a file which will display multiple data points. `MakeCommand` should actually create three related commands. What I meant to do was

```
\newcommand*{\temp}{}
\newcommand*{\MakeCommand}[1]
{
    \renewcommand*{\temp}
    {
        % store spaceless version of parameter
        \StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{}
    }
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname the\temp\endcsname{}% empty variable for use further ahead
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname \temp\endcsname[1]
    {
        % store value of data point
        \expandafter\renewcommand\csname the\temp \endcsname{#1}
    }
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname print\temp\endcsname
    {
        % print out formatted data point
        \textbf{\temp:} \csname\the\temp\endcsname
    }
}
```

So, `MakeCommands{Date of Birth}` would create three commands

- `\theDateofBirth`, which is initially empty
- `\DateofBirth`, which the user can later call to define `\theDateofBirth`
- `\printDateofBirth`, which prints out the data point

For example, `\DateofBirth{August 31, 2016}` would cause `\printDateofBirth` to output "**Date of Birth:** August 31, 2016".

Comment: Why not just supply the name *without* spaces?

Comment: Can you maybe provide an example of why this would be helpful? (or is it for fun?) Why not simply do something like `\makeatletter \newcommand\xxx[1]{\@nameuse{the#1}} \makeatother` then use it like `\xxx{Date of Birth}`?  (Not that I'd do this in one of my own documents.)

Comment: @Werner: Woops. I was going to add that as a note at the end of my question but forgot. I've added to the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to remove are spaces, the kernel function `\zap@space` is what you need:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\MakeCommand}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname the\zap@space #1 \@empty\endcsname
}
\makeatother
\MakeCommand{Date of Birth}{TEST}

\begin{document}

\theDateofBirth

\end{document}
```

I have changed the syntax for `\MakeCommand` to allow specifying the replacement text or it would be pretty useless.

However, the `the` prefix is not really well chosen.

The (slower) implementation with `\StrSubstitute`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\MakeCommand}[1]{%
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{}[\temp]%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname the\temp\endcsname
}

\MakeCommand{Date of Birth}{TEST}

\begin{document}

\theDateofBirth

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that makes use of expandable replacements, related to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313585/21930). This adds a whole system of expandable replacements, so it's not just about spaces. Once you do

```
\setfreplace{removespaces}{ }{}
```

you can say `\freplace{removespaces}{Date of Birth}` and it will substitute every space into nothing (i.e., removing the spaces) leaving `DateofBirth` *expandably*.

Altough may be you shouldn't use `\the...` in the names, as that naming convention is used in LaTeX for other things. May be `\TheDateofBirth`, `\showDateofBirth` or `\printDateofBirth`.

Here is an expl3 solution

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_generate_variant:Nn { c }

\NewDocumentCommand \setfreplace { m +m +m }
 {
  \freplace_set:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \freplace { +m +m }
 {
  \freplace:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\quark_new:N \q_freplace
\cs_new:Npn \freplace:nn #1 #2
 {
  \exp_not:f { \use:c { freplace_#1:n } { #2 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \freplace_set:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_#1:n } ##1
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_#1_auxi:nw } { } ##1 { \exp_not:N \q_freplace }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_#1_auxi:nw } ##1 ##2 ##
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_#1_nobraces:nfn }
     { ##1 } { \exp_not:c { freplace_#1_do:n } { ##2 } }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_#1_nobraces:nnn } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_#1_auxii:nn } { ##1 ##2 }
   }
  \cs_generate_variant:cn { freplace_#1_nobraces:nnn } { nf }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_#1_auxii:nn } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:N \str_if_eq:nnTF { \exp_not:N \q_freplace } { ##2 }
     { \exp_stop_f: ##1 }
     {
      \exp_not:c { freplace_#1_addbraces:nfw }
       { ##1 } { \exp_not:c { freplace_#1:n } { ##2 } }
     }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_#1_addbraces:nnw } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_#1_auxi:nw } { ##1 { ##2 } }
   }
  \cs_generate_variant:cn { freplace_#1_addbraces:nnw } { nf }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_#1_do:n } ##1
   {
    \exp_not:N \tl_if_empty:nTF { ##1 }
     { \exp_stop_f: }
     {
      \exp_not:c { freplace_#1_auxiii:nww }
       { } ##1 \exp_not:n { #2 \q_freplace \q_stop }
     }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_#1_auxiii:nww } ##1 ##2 #2 ##3 \q_stop
   {
    \exp_not:N \str_if_eq:nnTF { \exp_not:N \q_freplace } { ##3 }
     { \exp_stop_f: ##1 ##2 }
     {
      \exp_not:c { freplace_#1_auxiii:nww }
       { ##1 ##2 \exp_not:n { #3 } } ##3 \exp_not:N \q_stop
     }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \freplace:nn { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tl_replace_nested:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \freplace_set:nnn { _tmp_ } { #2 } { #3 }
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \freplace:nV { _tmp_ } #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setfreplace{removespaces}{ }{}

\newcommand*{\MakeCommand}[1]
{\expandafter\newcommand\csname the\freplace{removespaces}{#1}\endcsname{TEST}}

\MakeCommand{Date of Birth}

\begin{document}
    \theDateofBirth
\end{document}
```

After the update, here's a full command (I use commands from `etoolbox` to ease the code, which has expansion in account)

```
\newcommand*\temp{}
\newcommand*\MakeCommand[1]
 {\edef\temp{\freplace{removespaces}{#1}}%
  \csdef{the\temp}{}%
  \csedef{\temp}##1{\csdef{the\temp}{##1}}%
  \csedef{print\temp}{\unexpanded{\textbf{#1:}} \noexpand\csuse{the\temp}}}
```

---

And here another solution, a little bit less robust, without expl3 (in case you fear it and don't want to use it for some reason)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\long\def\usefirst#1#2{#1}
\long\def\usesecond#1#2{#2}
\def\strcmp#1#2{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}=0 \expandafter\usefirst\else\expandafter\usesecond\fi}
\def\strempty#1{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\expandafter\usefirst\else\expandafter\usesecond\fi}

\def\endreplace{\endreplace}
\def\nestedreplace#1{\csuse{nestedreplace:#1}}
\def\newnestedreplace#1#2#3{%
  \csdef{nestedreplace:#1}##1{\csuse{nestedreplace:#1:A}##1{\endreplace}}%
  \csdef{nestedreplace:#1:A}##1##{\csuse{doreplacement:#1}{##1}\csuse{nestedreplace:#1:B}}%
  \csdef{nestedreplace:#1:B}##1{\strcmp{##1}{\endreplace}{}
    {{\csuse{nestedreplace:#1}{##1}}\csuse{nestedreplace:#1:A}}}%
  \csdef{doreplacement:#1}##1{\strempty{#1}{}{\csuse{doreplacement:#1:A}{}##1#2\endreplace\qend}}%
  \csdef{doreplacement:#1:A}##1##2#2##3\qend{\strcmp{\endreplace}{##3}
    {\unexpanded{##1##2}}{\csuse{doreplacement:#1:A}{##1##2#3}##3\qend}}%
}

\newnestedreplace{removespaces}{ }{}

\newcommand*{\MakeCommand}[1]
{\expandafter\newcommand\csname the\nestedreplace{removespaces}{#1}\endcsname{TEST}}

\MakeCommand{Date of Birth}

\begin{document}
    \theDateofBirth
\end{document}
```

Comment: Done, removed; it was there for no reason.