# How come the catcode of ' is 12 while ' is let to be a macro?

Tags: math-mode, macros, tex-core

`'` is defined in `latex.ltx` as follows

```
\def\active@math@prime{^\bgroup\prim@s}
{\catcode`\'=\active \global\let'\active@math@prime}
\def\prim@s{%
  \prime\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s}
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
\def\pr@@@s#1{\prim@s}
\def\pr@@@t#1#2{#2\egroup}
```

I can see that the catcode of `'` is changed to `\active` in a group.
When the group ends, the catcode of `'` falls back to 12 (other).
So how could it possibly be that `$f'$` means `$f\active@math@prime$`?

I also tested

```
\catcode`!=12
{\catcode`!=\active \global\let!=\active@math@prime}
$f!!!$
```

It does not give the same result as $f'''$.
What happens to `'`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key is `\mathcode` set to hexadecimal 8000 (decimal 32768), which will set `!` active, but only in math mode.  Also, `\pr@m@s` needs redefinition to point to `!` rather than `'`.

Ref: [How can I make every occurrence of `+` and `-` be replaced by a macro, but only in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392072/how-can-i-make-every-occurrence-of-and-be-replaced-by-a-macro-but-only)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\catcode`!=12
\mathcode\number`\!="8000 %
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx!\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}

{\catcode`!=\active \global\let!=\active@math@prime}
$f!!!$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you needed **both** `!` and `'` to function in the prime way, you could *really* edit `\pr@m@s`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\catcode`!=12
\mathcode\number`\!="8000 %
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
  \ifx!\@let@token
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi\fi}

{\catcode`!=\active \global\let!=\active@math@prime}
$f!'!^3$
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK so I didn't need to define `!` nor did I need a back up of `'`. But that `\mathcode` is (probably) exactly what I am missing.

Comment: A character with `\mathcode` set to `"8000` is not really active: only when TeX is processing math codes it gets replaced by its definition as if it were active. If you try `$\edef\test{'}\show\test$`, you'll see that no expansion is done to `'` even if TeX is in math mode. Also, only characters with category code 11 or 12 can be math active.

Comment: @egreg I did think that maybe it is active in math so I tried `$\def'{what?}$`. And I got inaccessible. Now the rule is clear.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, both for the edit and clarifying comment.