# Is it possible to make a command that makes "LRA" a shortcut for \Leftrightarrow?

Tags: macros

I have to write `\Leftrightarrow` quite often, and i am currently using a macro for it, but it isn't working too well. Is it possible to make it so that when i type `LRA` in a math field, that it then outputs it as a `\Leftrightarrow`?
Thanks a lot for any and all help!

Comment: In my opinion, if this practice is generalised, it makes the code harder to read and harder to debug. This is more a problem for your editor: most editors should easily make typing `\LRA` a shortcut for displaying `\leftrightarrow`.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  the way your question is stated makes it seem like you want to avoid typing the backslash, as well as shortening the "name".  is this really so?  (if so, the answer is, well, maybe it's possible, but *you really don't want to do that*.)

Comment: Yes i am aware that it is harder to read, but is it possible to just write LRA instead og \LRA, and if so how do you do it?

Comment: @Chrisw85 possible? Yes. Advisable? No. You could set it up in your editor (e.g. VIM's latex-suite uses similar sequences as replacement, typing `SCH` becomes `\chapter`, while typing `SSE` becomes `\section`).

Comment: and [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Alright guys, thanks for the advice on keeping the backslash :) i think i will stick to it then

Comment: Depending on the editor you use you can probably make it automatically replace LRA with `\leftrightarrow` -- for example, this is easy with vim.

Comment: the alleged duplicate says nothing about defining a command *without a backslash*.  that aspect of this question deserves its own answer as to *why* it's a bad idea.  i'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107014/automatically-apply-special-formatting-to-selected-words-in-text https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248632/highlight-every-occurrence-of-a-list-of-words?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You never know but sometime in the future you may write about gunnery and use LRA as a shorthand for Long Range Artillery and then be surprised when it gets typeset as a `\leftrightarrow` (or an error).

Comment: Off-topic: @Chrisw85 If you try to edit your question (without saving) you will see how we highlighting the in-line code

Comment: @koleygr you can use already defined \iff which is faster to type but displays a longer version of \Leftrightarrow.

Comment: @user2987828 ... I think you  wanted to ping the OP instead of me ....

Comment: @Chrisw85 you can use already defined \iff which is faster to type but displays a longer version of \Leftrightarrow.

Comment: @koleygr oh sorry. Done. The OP has still 1 rep, so I guess he might not catch that notification at all...

Comment: @user2987828 ... It is his post ... If he log in again... he will be notified.... Happy TeXing

Answer (score 1):

`\newcommand{\LRA}{\leftrightarrow}` should do the trick. You can find more detailed information [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros), for example.

Comment: I think in this case I'd use `\let\LRA\leftrightarrow`.

Comment: the question asks for input `LRA` not `\LRA`

Comment: Yes i am asking for LRA and not \LRA. By the way, how do you make that grey box around the important text, so to speak?

Comment: @MaxD `\iff` is already defined. @Chrisw85 The grey boxes are created by ticks: `

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion in [How could LaTeX replace the tokens `<=` by the command `\leq`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311485/5764), you can use LuaLaTeX to replace all `LRA`s in your code with `\Leftrightarrow`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function do_LRA ( buff )
  buff = string.gsub ( buff , "LRA",   "\\Leftrightarrow ")
  return buff
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
    "process_input_buffer" , do_LRA, "do_LRA" )}}

\begin{document}

$ <== LRA ==> L RA << >> LR A -+ +- L R A == LRA =[ =] $

The Literacy Research Association (LRA) \ldots

The Literacy Research Association (L{}RA) \ldots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. But it is questionable if it is usable.

The interesting point of your task is that you need not use `\LRA` but directly `LRA`. Then you can try the following code:

```
\mathchardef\mL=\mathcode`L 
\mathcode`L="8000
{\catcode`L=13 \gdef L{\futurelet\next\lraA}}
\def\lraA{\ifx\next R\expandafter\lraB \else \mL\fi}
\def\lraB#1{\futurelet\next\lraC}
\def\lraC{\ifx\next A\expandafter\lraD \else \mL R\fi}
\def\lraD#1{\Leftrightarrow}

% test:

Aha LRA in text.
In math: $LR, L, LRA$

\bye
```