# Generate automatic revision's numbering tabular

Tags: tables, macros, counters, loops

**Situation**

I have to make a cover template for a document. At the end of the page, I have to add the revision number with other useful info like this example:

```
\begin{tabular}{lccl}
    Revision 0 & 06-11-2014 & Initial Release & John Smith \\
    Revision 1 & 06-12-2014 & Changed something & Joe Blow \\
    ...
\end{tabular}
```

**Objective**

In the TEX document, the user would have to add their revision like this:

```
\AddRevision{06-11-2014}{Initial Release}{John Smith}
\AddRevision{06-12-2014}{Changed something}{Joe Blow}
...
\createFrontPage
```

When generating the PDF, this should automatically generate the tabular above. Note that the revision's number is automatically increase by 1 at each AddRevision.

**What I have tried**

I'm not familiar with Latex macros, so this is what I have for the moment. I just don't know if I'm close to the solution or if I'm doing totally wrong. Here's the code in my CLS file:

```
\newCounter{RowCounter}
\def\AddRev#1,#2,#3{\RevDate{#1}, \RevDesc{#2}, \RevAuthor{#3} \stepCounter{RowCounter}}

\newCounter{i}
\newcommand{\RevisionRows}
{
    \forloop{i}{0}{\value{i} < \value{RowCounter}}
    {
        Revision \arabic{i} & \RevDate & \RevDesc & \RevAuthor \\
    }
}    

\newcommand{\createFrontPage}
{
   % some stuff
   \begin{tabular}{lccl}
       \RevisionRows    
   \end{tabular}
}
```

**Questions**

Is my objective possible ? If yes, What am I doing wrong ?
 What's the best and clean solution ? Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way:

[image]

### Notes:

I would recommend you put everything prior to the first `\AddRevision` in a separate package and have the users add the revisions *before* `\begin{document}`.

### References:

- [Build tabular content via \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175568/build-tabular-content-via-foreach)
- [How to automatically add text immediately after \begin{document}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14135/how-to-automatically-add-text-immediately-after-begindocument)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175568/build-tabular-content-via-foreach
\newcommand*{\MyTempTableTokens}{}%
\makeatletter
    \newtoks\@tabtoks
    %%% assignments to \@tabtoks must be global, because they are done in \foreach
    \newcommand\AddTableTokens[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
    \newcommand\eAddTableTokens[1]{%
      \protected@edef\MyTempTableTokens{#1}%
      \expandafter\AddTableTokens\expandafter{\MyTempTableTokens}%
    }
    %%% variable should always be operated on always locally or always globally
    \newcommand*\ResetTableTokens{\global\@tabtoks{}}
    \newcommand*\PrintTableTokens{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother



\newcounter{RowCounter}
\newcommand{\AddRevision}[3]{%
    \stepcounter{RowCounter}%
    \eAddTableTokens{Revision \arabic{RowCounter} & #1 & #2 & #3 \\}%
}%

\newcommand{\createFrontPage}{%
   % some stuff
   \begin{tabular}{lccl}
       \PrintTableTokens    
   \end{tabular}%
   \clearpage
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \createFrontPage%
}%

%-----------------------------------------------------------


\AddRevision{06-11-2014}{Initial Release}{John Smith}
\AddRevision{06-12-2014}{Changed something}{Joe Blow}

\begin{document}

     main document here

\end{document}
```