# \AtBeginDocument content seems to be ignored by htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, html, htlatex, latex2html

It appears that the content inserted via `\AtBeginDocument` is being ignored by `htlatex`. Is there a workaround to this other than not using `\AtBeginDocument`?

To reproduce save the MWEs below and run

```
htlatex <filename>
```

The only difference between the two is that one uses `\AtBeginDocument{\Dedication}` and the other has `\Dedication` in the main body of the document.

Using `\Dedication` in the main body produces

```html
<!--l. 9--><p class="indent" >   This is dedicated to me as I wrote it!! :-)

   <h2 class="chapterHead"><span class="titlemark">Chapter&#x00A0;1</span><br /><a 
 id="x1-10001"></a>First Chapter</h2> Text for first chapter.  
</body></html>
```

whereas using `\AtBeginDocument{\Dedication}` produces

```html
<!--l. 11--><p class="indent" >

   <h2 class="chapterHead"><span class="titlemark">Chapter&#x00A0;1</span><br /><a 
 id="x1-10001"></a>First Chapter</h2> Text for first chapter.  
</body></html>
```

Note that the dedication text is missing.

### References

- [How to automatically add text immediately after \begin{document}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14135/how-to-automatically-add-text-immediately-after-begindocument)

---

### Code: `Dedication`

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand*{\Dedication}{%
    \clearpage
    This is dedicated to me as I wrote it!! :-)
}

\begin{document}
\Dedication
\chapter{First Chapter}
Text for first chapter.
\end{document}
```

---

### Code:  `\AtBeginDocument{\Dedication}`

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand*{\Dedication}{%
    \clearpage
    This is dedicated to me as I wrote it!! :-)
}

\AtBeginDocument{\Dedication}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
Text for first chapter.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that lot of things is happening at begin document in `tex4ht`. This is the moment when patches from `.4ht` files are loaded, and `html` header is printed. So your dedication text is printed before any html tags in your example. Probably easiest solution is to use `etoolbox` command `\AfterEndPreamble`, which print content after all `\AtBeginDocument` commands are done:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand*{\Dedication}{%
    \clearpage
    This is dedicated to me as I wrote it!! :-)
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\AtBeginDocument{\Dedication}%
\AfterEndPreamble{\Dedication}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
Text for first chapter.
\end{document}
```

and the result:

```xml
<!--l. 11--><p class="indent" >   This is dedicated to me as I wrote it!! :-)

</p>
   <h2 class="chapterHead"><span class="titlemark">Chapter&#x00A0;1</span><br /><a 
 id="x1-10001"></a>First Chapter</h2> Text for first chapter.  
</body></html>
```