# Define command that contains a command that cannot be executed in the preamble

Tags: macros

I have a command like this:

```
\def\command#1{%
    \calc{#1}%
    \doStuff%
}
```

`\calc` sets certain lengths based on the current size. As such it cannot be executed in the preamble. This works as expected.

However, I want to define a new command

```
\def\command2{%
    \command{default}%
}
```

How can I do that? I can’t put the above in the preamble since the compiler is trying to evaluate `\calc` and the expected errors occur.

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible to answer without knowing what you're trying to achieve. What's `\calc` doing, precisely?

Comment: please make your example a real test document that shows the problem, and state your expected outcome. You can not have a command `\command2` but the replacement text is not evaluated at all so you can make the definition anywhere

Comment: If you want to defer something to not executed in the preable you can use `\AtBeginDocument{}` or `\AtEndPreamble{}`.

Comment: @egreg \calc is a bunch of \setlength and \settoheight.

Comment: @PeterGrill This worked. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterGrill If you post an answer I’ll accept it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to defer something to not executed in the preable you can use `\AtBeginDocument{}` or `\AtEndPreamble{}`.

References:

- [How to automatically add text immediately after \begin{document}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14135/4301).

Answer (score 0):

```
\def\command#1{%
    \calc{#1}%
    \doStuff%
}
% ...
\def\command2{%
    \command{default}%
}
```

---

I suppose you are misinterpreting error-messages:

`\def` does not trigger but does prevent evaluation.

But when reading/tokenizing the .tex-input file TeX does tokenize the sequence `\command2` as control-word-token `\command` trailed by the explicit character token `2` of category 12(other).

Thus with `\def\command2{\command{default}}` the control-word-token `\command` is redefined to be something that is delimited by `2` and that as replacement-text delivers the control-word-token `\command` for calling itself (which implies unwanted recursion), trailed by character-tokens `{`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `a`, `u`, `l`, `t` and `}`.

Any attempt at expanding the macro `\command` without a trailing `2` yields a message about usage of `\command` not matching its definition.

Even if the first instance of `\command` is trailed by `2` you  get this message because in this case expansion of `\command 2` yields `\command {default}` where you have an instance of the control-word-token `\command` which is not trailed by `2`.

---

Between `\makeatletter..\makeatother` you can probably do something like

```
\def\command#1{%
    \calc{#1}%
    \doStuff%
}%
% ... 
% defining the command:
\@namedef{command2}{%
    \command{default}%
}%
% ...
% calling/using the command:
\@nameuse{command2}%
```

(`\@namedef` / `\@nameuse` internally use `\csname..\endcsname` for constructing control-word-tokens whose names may also contain digits like `2`.)