# What Even is a TeX Distribution?

Tags: distributions

Is there a standard, formal or defacto, for what exactly a TeX distribution is and what programs/features need to be supported to be a TeX distribution?

I feel like this question has had to have been asked before, and while my searching turned up [a number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239199/latex-distributions-what-are-their-main-differences) [of similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-lualatex) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13541/difference-between-latex-latex2e-latex3) none got at the heart of what I was after.

For context, I'm trying to understand what TeX and LaTeX are from a *software* point of view.  I've been using TeX/LaTeX for years via the `pdflatex` command or indirectly via `pandoc` but I've never really had a good feeling for what, exactly, I'm installing when I install a `TeX` distribution.

For example, right now on my Mac I have a `pdflatex` command that's located at

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
```

and the `/Library/TeX/texbin/` folder has a few hundred binaries in it.  So is a TeX distribution just folks deciding which of these programs to make available?  Or is there more to it than that?

Put another way: If I wanted to create a new nominal TeX distribution (which, trust me, I don't) what exactly would I be doing/have to do?

I realize this is a pretty big question with answers that could have varying levels of detail. If the answer is RTFM that's legit -- but I'd appreciate a pointer to *which part* of *which manual* I want to be reading.

Comment: `and the /Library/TeX/texbin/ folder has a few hundred binaries in it. So is a TeX distribution just folks deciding which of these programs to make available? Or is there more to it than that?`  just that and the other non executable files such as latex packages, fonts, documentation, ....

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21863/tex-distribution-and-engine

Comment: For slightly more user oriented overview, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66470/2693

Comment: And on what "counts" as a distribution, it's possible to make quite bare bones versions. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397174/2693