# Are there any typographical improvements planned for LaTeX3?

Tags: typography, latex3

I have read a few posts about the changes to LaTeX in the upcoming "version",
are there planned any changes to how LaTeX renders typography? Regarding kerning, spacing and all the "fancy" things `microtype` does today. 
I know that LaTeX has some problems with rivers and lakes today, and I do not know if those are possible to fix. But in that regard does LaTeX3 do anything different, for improved typography?
This is not a critique, just a question from a curious user. 
If there are any improvements, a list and some examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related questions might be http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70901/typesetting-limitations-of-latex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27440/what-cant-tex-do.

Comment: I would consider the ongoing development of packages (which makes doing things easier) as typographical improvements.  But maybe that's off the mark of what you are asking.

Comment: IMHO none of the problems you mention (e.g. rivers and lakes) can be changed at the macro level - unless one takes the ConTeXt approach and reimplements parts of TeX in Lua (e.g. the parbuilder). AFAIK this is not planned for LaTeX3 as LaTeX tries to be engine-agnostic.

Answer (score 9):

The purpose of LaTeX3 is to *enable* typographical improvements rather than to provide them.

The stable bits ([expl3](/questions/tagged/expl3), [xparse](/questions/tagged/xparse), [l3keys](/questions/tagged/l3keys), among others) have so far provided more flexible ways to program LaTeX. Next on the agenda (according to [this thread on the LaTeX3 list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.latex.latex3/1714)) is the template concept, since

> the output and galley ideas need template, template needs xparse and xparse needs expl3.

The template concept (see *[Using LaTeX3’s xtemplate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117984/2966)* ) or the proposed CSS-like “LaTeX Database (LDB)” are still works-in-progress, but it is there that many typographical improvements will become possible. (Others will require the output and galley ideas, which are further yet from reality.)

But these all relate to making accessible what TeX already makes possible. Things like `microtype` or river-detection require modifications of the engine itself. This has been done—the additions of `microtype` in PDFTeX and XeTeX are examples—but the easiest way to implement such changes is to use the hooks LuaTeX provides.

I hope that a LaTeX3-based format, being more modular and having a better separation of responsibilities, will allow for “cleaner” Lua-based changes to the typesetting process, but that would be the extent of LaTeX3’s involvement in these changes.