# About the features of LaTeX3

Tags: koma-script, latex3

Can someone please provide me the features available in LaTeX3. The reason for me to post this question is that I have not started to learn about KOMA-Script. I am aware of how powerful it is. But now should I go for KOMA-Script or LaTeX3?

Comment: I think you are confused with [koma-script](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/koma-script/info) a versatile bundle of classes and packages with [latex3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/latex3/info) a next version of latex2e that has [expl3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/expl3/info) as programming layer for LaTeX3.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

KOMA-Script is a family of documentclasses (`scrbook` `scrartcl` `scrreprt` `scrlettr2`), which allow you to customize your documents more than the standard classes (`book` `article` `report` `letter`) do.

LaTeX3 is right now mainly a new programming language which is not directly useful for creating documents. It is meant to be the new way to write packages and classes.

In the future LaTeX3 aims to be a complete replacement to LaTeX2e, with perhaps an entirely new command set to write documents, and also a ton of internal improvements to how things are handled. This is as for now a work in progress.

Comment: Small correction: KOMA-Script is a family of document classes _and_ packages. Some of these packages can be used independently of KOMA-Script classes.

Answer (score 17):

LaTeX3 is not meant to be a substitute for document classes such as Memoir or those in the KOMA-Scripts bundle.

Currently, LaTeX3 defines a new programming language for *class* and *package* authors called `expl3`, and it provides a small number of packages directed towards *document* authors, such as `xparse`. The latter facilitates the creation of user-defined document commands and environments. A famous example of a package written in `expl3` is `siunitx`.

For now, as a normal user of classes and packages (even if programmed using LaTeX3 concepts) you shouldn't worry too much about LaTeX3. However, the plan is that LaTeX3 should take the place of LaTeX2e, which would then get obsoleted.

Comment: LaTeX3 is much more than a programming language (which is called expl3) but much of it right now is in development or even only an idea :)

Comment: @cgnieder: Aha. So far, I thought `expl3` stands for 'experimental LaTeX3', and one day, when it is ready, that is, after having been turned into a format, it will be called 'LaTeX3'.

Comment: @AlexG See http://latex-project.org/papers/2013-10-24-latex3.pdf and `texdoc xtemplate` (where the consensus over `xtemplate` is that it needs to reworked, but the basic concepts are sound).  Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118015/17423.

Comment: thanks @SeanAllred. So Alex, please do me a favor and retract the above statement it is simply not true; or only true for expl3 whic his the underlying programming language "for LaTeX3". By the way, expl3 indeed stood at one point for "EXperimental Programing Language" and the abbrev got stuck. But you can happily think of it now as EXtended Programming Language" given its abilities :-)

Comment: @Frank: I am not sure if the answer is better now. Feel free to edit and improve it.

Comment: ... or even turn it into cwiki.

Comment: @AlexG “obsoleted” is a difficult term in tex -- people like to hang on.  when latex 2e appeared, it obsoleted latex 2.09, but people still (20 years later) turn up with a 2.09 document that they compile through the compatibility mode support in 2e.  latex 3 offers several different moves away from the original, but still inter-works (in the sense of being plugged-in to 2e documents).  how many "pure" 2e documents will we see in 2034, i wonder?

Comment: @AlexG First you say some of the packages *are* aimed at document authors. Then you say not to worry about LaTeX3. This is a bit misleading, I think. *If* you are the sort of document author who uses `\newcommand`, `\def` etc., then it is well worth looking at what these packages have to offer. For example, it is possible to avoid the use of TeX commands such as `\def` in a wider range of cases than with only the commands from 2e. If you don't use custom commands etc. much, you obviously have little to gain.