# Is still xtemplates recommended for document class writers?

Tags: latex3, documentclass-writing, xtemplate

Suppose I'd like to create a LaTeX class based on another one (say `article`), with e.g. quotations or theorems with specific designs (say as `tcolorbox` boxes): is it still nowadays recommended to rely on `xtemplates` for this?

Aside question: are there any changes to be made, nearly 10 years later, to [this instructive answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118015/18401) of Frank Mittelbach about `xtemplates`?