# How will the LaTeX3 format look?

Tags: expl3, latex3

Can someone give me an idea (if it is at all possible) about how the document structure will be in the LaTeX3 format. Will it still start with a `\documentclass` and use `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`, will we still load a list  (hopefully shorter) of packages in the preamble, etc.? And will the awkward syntax of `expl3` only affect programmers? So can I continue writing

```
\begin{equation} 
    \alpha^2 + \beta^2 = \int_a^b e^x\, dx
\end{equation}
```

like I have always done? Or will all of these nice and short commands be replaced by odd `expl3` commands with awkwardly long names?

Comment: The only answer at this moment could be: TBD

Comment: @PaulGessler Well yes and no: `expl3` is the code layer and is not meant to replace document syntax. On the other hand, the latter is to be decided.

Comment: So basically, development of the overall LaTeX3 format (=heart of LaTeX3) is hardly even in its initial stages? After 20 years?

Comment: @Gaussler The document level syntax is only a small part of the work: indeed, using a layer approach the entire point is to avoid the issue that LaTeX2e has in the sense interface and implementation are tied together.

Comment: @JosephWright, that is good to hear. Speaking of this, what is the current status of the entire LaTeX3 project? Are we getting closer to a release? I have read the news on the LaTeX website, but it is difficult to find the answer to that question.

Comment: @Gaussler Apart from the official answer (“to be decided”), I think that the best we can wish is that the LaTeX3 format keeps what's good, and changes what's not that good. Is there anything wrong with your input? I don't think so, so I hope it stays the same. At the same time, I hope that things get better in other areas; for instance, I think the `split` environment is unnecessary, and should be used by default, so you could use `&` and ``\\`` inside that `equation` (just an example).

Comment: Fully agreed. And I think it would be more convenient to be able to select actively which equations to enumerate. So I would like to use `equation*` and apply some `\yesnumber` command if I want an equation number; this is better than the current situation where you must use `equation` and write `\nonumber` after all the other lines.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In 2010, Joseph Wright wrote in [What new bits have already been implemented in Latex3? Will my current documents (with many packages) still compile with Latex3?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397/what-new-bits-have-already-been-implemented-in-latex3-will-my-current-documents/400#400)

> What is not yet formalised is how LaTeX3 will look for the end user. I
>   think, however, that we can be confident that the current basic model
>
> ```
> \documentclass{<something>}
> \begin{document}
> Some text \emph{with italics}. 
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> will survive (the project will fail if it does not).

But the best answer to your question probably is [What can *I* do to help the LaTeX3 Project](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45838/what-can-i-do-to-help-the-latex3-project/46427#46427) by Frank Mittelbach. (Read the whole answer, and the section "Document Interface Layer" in particular).